# Dynamically altering table structure based on number of cells

Tags: php, html, twig

**Background**

I'm making a front page where I use Twig to create one table for each Playlist, and each playlist contains some links to videos. It looks something like this.

```
{% for playlist in playlists %}
    <table class="table table-condensed table-responsive table-nonfluid">
        <tr>
            <th>{{ playlist.name | title}}</th>
        </tr>
        {% for video in playlist.videos %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ video.name }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endfor%}
```

**Desired outcome**

I want to have each table use

- one column if there are 10 or fewer videos in a playlist
- two columns if there are 11 or more videos in a playlist
- three columns if there are 21 or more videos in a playlist
- no more than three columns

And if the table has two or more columns, the first column should be filled first (with ten entries) before the first cell of the second column. And same story for second and third columns.

**Question**

Can this be done using Twig? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in Twig, but you could just use size_of($videos) in plain php. Then have the 3 cases (<= 10, >=21, else ) and then do different echo's ...